# Where do i put the } symbol?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

guys i need some help im getting the error:  "} expected" please help. I have only been doing this for one day and following some older tutorials

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float moveSpeed;
        public Rigidbody theRB;
        public float jumpForce;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            theRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            theRB.velocity =  new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, theRB.velocity.y, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed);

            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))       
            (
                theRB.velocity = new Vector3(theRB.velocity.x, jumpForce, theRB.velocity.z));
            )      
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain your problem in details

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code and the error message and add it to your post? It is cut off in the image, and much easier to debug in text format.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! please do not post screenshots - copy and paste text into your questions instead. this way it's going to be easier to find and answer

Comment: to answer your question, replace single quotes (') with double quotes (") around your strings.

Comment: replace single quote in `Input.GetButtonDown('Jump')` to double quotes

Comment: You should include code as text, as well as the error message. This allows other people to find your question in future. SO is intended to be a collection of high quality questions and answers, and questions are generally expected to be useful for other people in the future. That is: the contents of your question should be useful to someone else having the same problem. As an image, it makes things hard to find because search engines cannot index the text in the image.

Comment: In addition to taking the [tour], reading [ask], and what has been suggested above, you should be using curly braces in your `if` statement. `if (condition) { ... }` (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) for more information)

Comment: As for your problem (since your question is closed), you will note that `'` and `"` have different meanings. `' '` indicates a single character, whereas `" "` indicates one or more characters forming a `string`. Clearly "jump" is 4 characters, so `'jump'` is incorrect. I also doubt there is a keyboard button called "jump".

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this code:

```
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))       
        (
            theRB.velocity = new Vector3(theRB.velocity.x, jumpForce, theRB.velocity.z));
        )
```

to this:

```
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))       
        {//notice the brackets here
            theRB.velocity = new Vector3(theRB.velocity.x, jumpForce, theRB.velocity.z);
        }//notice the brackets here
```

Comment: `theRB.velocity = new Vector3(theRB.velocity.x, jumpForce, theRB.velocity.z));`

should be 

`theRB.velocity = new Vector3(theRB.velocity.x, jumpForce, theRB.velocity.z);`

too